# Prevent that a MySQL row updates two times at once? (nodejs mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have this code in my server nodejs file to update a row in a mysql db with the mysql module using socket.io that's updating every second:

```
var query_update = mysql.query('UPDATE `auctions` \
SET `random` = ?,`price`= ?,`datetime` = ? WHERE `id` = ?', \
[rand, price, t, auction.id]);  
console.log('\n'+time()+query_update.sql+'\n');
```

I don't know why, but some specific row entries will be updated twice at a time. Is there a way to prevent this somehow? **Maybe even mysql-wise that a row can only be updated every x seconds once?**

I also used milliseconds as console.log output (in function time()) to investigate if this happens some milliseconds after the first update, but it happens right in the same moment like this:

[image]

Other auctions just updates one time and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Can you log incoming request and check if them come twice? Basically, it doesn't to be a server-side problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I `SELECT`ed data and didn't used `GROUP BY` and I used `LEFT JOIN` on that previous `SELECT`-statement. So he selected the same row twice.